# writing a .csv file - independent of the culture

Tags: c#

In German langauage- decimal seperators are , and value seperators are ";" . In English/other languages, decimal seperators are . and values seperators are ",".

I want to create a .csv file indepedent of the current culture. I mean always the .csv file should have "." has decimal seperators and "," has value seperators.

The code for this given below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;

namespace CSV_FILE_FORMAT
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string aFileName = "result.csv";
            FileStream aFileStream = new FileStream(aFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            StreamWriter m_StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(aFileStream);
            double[] values = new double[] { 10.5, 20.3, 30.2 };
            for(int i = 0; i < values.Length;i++)
            {
                m_StreamWriter.Write(values[i].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                m_StreamWriter.Write(",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is if OS is in German. The decimal seperators are shown "," instead of ".".

Please let me know the code is missing something.

Comment: _"The problem with this code is if OS is in German. The decimal seperators are shown "," instead of "."."_ That should be prevented by the use of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. So there must be somewhat else i'm overlooked yet.

Comment: m_StreamWriter.Write(values[i].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); I am using culture.invariantculture. but still i am not able to get the proper value.

Comment: The provided code works fine (except for closing the resources ;-)) on a German OS (Windows 7) and the doubles are formated with a point "." as expected by the comments. Even if the culture settings are set to a ",".

Comment: Seems you solved the core problem but are testing it wrong.

Comment: This is the #1 reason why I prefer tab-separated values over comma-separated. My #2 reason - you can copy-paste TSV plaintext into MS Excel.

Answer (score 6):

You can probably get decimal separator and list separator from the current culture.

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(currentCultureName);
string decimalSeparator = culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
string listSeparator = culture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;
```

And, if the value being written contains any of the separators then, enclose the value within double quotes.

```
string val = values[i].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
if(val.Contains(decimalSeparator) || val.Contains(listSeparator))
{
    val = string.Format("\"{0}\"", val);
}
m_StreamWriter.Write(val);
m_StreamWriter.Write(listSeparator);
```

Current culture name can be something like this: "en-US" for United States of America.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution so solve the German culture problem is to embed those double values with quotes. Results:

```
English: "10.5","20.3","30.2"
German: "10,5","20,3","30,2"
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: IMHO, this would be a better solution, coherant with CSV parsers

Comment: A German Excel version expects `;` to be used as delimiter, though.

Comment: It depends very much on the reader part: German or Invariant.

Comment: @Јοеу I believe Microsoft Excel always expects `;` as delimiter for a "**comma**-separated-values file", regardless of culture.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution to this problem: CSV is *not* a file format definition (despite RFC 4180).

Excel, as an example, reads and saves csv using the localized list separator and localized data formats set by the user. This way, "Comma" in CSV does not mean a comma, but the generic list separator (for many EU countries this is the semicolon, as Tim Schmelter said).

If the values are enclosed in quotes, they are generally treated as strings. Excel tries to parse quoted elements of a CSV row anyway, so this may seem to work in very special cases.

The problem is that both writer and reader of a CSV file should use the same culture, otherwise problems will arise with nearly everything that is not a string (numbers are one, date/times are another source of problems).

I use an empirically derived solution for dates, consisting of the format string `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`. I observed that it allows for working date exchange between Excel and my programs, interchangeably in English or Italian.

I still have not found an universal solution for decimal numbers. I suspect Scientific notation may do, but have not had time to test.